# How to create Dictionary from Object List in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to create a Dictionary from a List of employees (Employee class contains 'full_name', 'salary', 'department' etc) in Python, where department becomes the dictionary keys and list of all employees of that department becomes the value of the dictionary?

I have tried to achieve the same using the following code, but I am sure that there is a better way to achieve the same result:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, department):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.department = department

    def __str__(self):
        return '[name: {self.name}, salary: {self.salary}, department: {self.department}]'.format(self=self)

employee_list = []

employee_list.append(Employee('Saroj',23023232, 'Finance'))
employee_list.append(Employee('Paul',23023232, 'HR'))
employee_list.append(Employee('Rose',230232, 'HR'))
employee_list.append(Employee('Mathew',233354, 'Security'))
employee_list.append(Employee('Amit',2323255, 'Finance'))
employee_list.append(Employee('Manisha',4435644, 'Finance'))
employee_list.append(Employee('John',2302332,'HR'))
employee_list.append(Employee('Edwin',909898, 'Finance'))

def get_emp_list_by_department(emp_list):
    emp_dict = {}
    for employee in emp_list:
        if getattr(employee, 'department') == 'HR':
            if emp_dict.get('HR') is None:
                emp_dict['HR'] = []
                emp_dict['HR'].append(employee)
            else:
                emp_dict['HR'].append(employee)
        elif getattr(employee, 'department') == 'Security':
            if emp_dict.get('Security') is None:
                emp_dict['Security'] = []
                emp_dict['Security'].append(employee)
            else:
                emp_dict['Security'].append(employee)
        elif getattr(employee, 'department') == 'Finance':
            if emp_dict.get('Finance') is None:
                emp_dict['Finance'] = []
                emp_dict['Finance'].append(employee)
            else:
                emp_dict['Finance'].append(employee)

    return emp_dict

emp_dic = get_emp_list_by_department(employee_list)
print(emp_dic)
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Please try and read your own subjectively and really think if it is answerable. We have no clue about departments or employees. Read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Show us some code and explain your specific problem in detail in order for us to be able to help

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I am extremely sorry for my poor quality question. I have edited my question and tried to make it more clear.

Comment: It is already better but still missing alot. First of all please show any code you already have trying to solve this problem. This is not a code sevice site, but a Q&A about code problems, so for that we need to see some code. Second there is still information missing like how do you have these employee objects (a list?). Again, please do read about [mre] and help us help you :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo I have added my code, can you please suggest me more concise code to achieve the result

Comment: @ChihebNexus I have added my code, which isn't very efficient, can you please suggest me better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: @Saroj this is already much better. Please take this notes for the next questions you ask and keep it as clear and informative as possible. It is now much deserves an answer and you can find mine below :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest way would be to use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). With this type of dict you can specify the default type of values, in case the key is not present. This way, you can just "assume" the key is present, and if it is not - a new value will be assigned automatically. So your `get_emp_list_by_department` can reduce all the way to be:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_emp_list_by_department(emp_list):
    emp_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for employee in emp_list:
        emp_dict[employee.department].append(employee)

    return emp_dict
```

And doing `get_emp_list_by_department(employee_list)` with your given data will give (after changing `__str__` to `__repr__` for convenient printing):

```
{'Finance': [[name: Saroj, salary: 23023232, department: Finance], 
             [name: Amit, salary: 2323255, department: Finance], 
             [name: Manisha, salary: 4435644, department: Finance], 
             [name: Edwin, salary: 909898, department: Finance]], 
 'HR': [[name: Paul, salary: 23023232, department: HR], 
       [name: Rose, salary: 230232, department: HR], 
       [name: John, salary: 2302332, department: HR]], 
 'Security': [[name: Mathew, salary: 233354, department: Security]]}
```

---

In general, even without `defaultdict`, all those `if/elif`s are not necessary. You can still just use the `department` dynamically, for example:

```py
def get_emp_list_by_department(emp_list):
    emp_dict = {}
    for employee in emp_list:
        dept = employee.department
        if not dept in emp_dict:
            emp_dict[dept] = []

        emp_dict[dept].append(employee)

    return emp_dict
```

Comment: "Thanks a lot " @Tomerikoo, I am primarily a Java developer, and learning Python. "defaultdict" is the magical function, I was looking for.

Comment: @Saroj happy to help. Python's standard libs are filled with little gems like this one and it takes time to get familiar with them. Happy to help you broaden the sheet a little bit ;)